# When creating a custom map class in c++ how to define and use a comparator in the template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a container that works like the STL using an array. One thing I am stuck on is how to implement a comparator object to the template

```
template <typename  K, typename V, typename KeyEqual = myEqualObject<K> >
class Map {
......
}
```

would that template header need to be repeated on all method bodies outside of the class ? i.e

```
template <typename K, typename V >
V& Map<K,V>::operator[] (K key) {
...
}
```

should be

```
template <typename  K, typename V, typename KeyEqual = myEqualObject<K> >
V& Map<K,V>::operator[] (K key) {
...
}
```

Also I am struggling with how to use/implement this extra object in my class to check if two key values are the same. Can anyone shed any light ?

I have looked around this subject but cannot find any examples in this context

Comment: Is this a toy project?  If not, you really should be just using the actual Standard Library, and not building this stuff yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would that template header need to be repeated on all method bodies outside of the class ?

You need all the template parameters, but there's no need to repeat the default arguments:

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename KeyEqual>
V& Map<K,V,KeyEqual>::operator[] (K key) {
...
}
```

> Also I am struggling with how to use/implement this extra object in my class to check if two key values are the same.

Following the example of the standard containers, store a comparator object in a (probably private) member variable:

```
KeyEqual equal;
```

initialise it in the constructor(s), allowing the user to supply one:

```
Map(/* arguments, */ KeyEqual equal = KeyEqual()) : 
    // initialisers,
    equal(equal)
{
    // anything else
}
```

and use it as a binary predicate:

```
if (equal(key1, key2)) {
    // treat them as equal
}
```

It can be implemented as a binary function class:

```
template <typename K> struct myEqualObject {
    bool operator()(K const & k1, K const & k2) {return k1 == k2;}
};
```

although I'd use `std::equal_to<K>` as the default, rather than rewriting my own version.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works perfectly + I understand it a lot more now !